# Zip function with arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, zip

I have a 2D array and a 3D array. I am trying to zip them together.

This is the code.

```
data1 = [
    [1, 1.0, 1.5, 500, 0.0, 0.0, ([[1, 2],[3, 4]])],
    [1, 1.0, 1.5, 500, 0.0, 0.5, ([[2, 3],[4, 5]])],
    [1, 1.5, 1.5, 500, 0.0, 0.0, ([[300, 499],[577, 699]])],
    [1, 1.5, 1.5, 500, 0.0, 0.5, ([[477, 599],[644, 788]])]
]

data2 = [
    [[0, 0, 90], [2, 3, 5]],
    [[4, 7, 8], [8, 4, 6]]
]


combination = [[(k, l) for k, l in zip(data1, row)] for row in data2]

print(combination)
```

It results in:

```
[[([1, 1.0, 1.5, 500, 0.0, 0.0, [[1, 2], [3, 4]]], [0, 0, 90]), 
  ([1, 1.0, 1.5, 500, 0.0, 0.5, [[2, 3], [4, 5]]], [2, 3, 5])], 
 [([1, 1.0, 1.5, 500, 0.0, 0.0, [[1, 2], [3, 4]]], [4, 7, 8]), 
  ([1, 1.0, 1.5, 500, 0.0, 0.5, [[2, 3], [4, 5]]], [8, 4, 6])]]
```

But I am trying to get:

```
[[([1, 1.0, 1.5, 500, 0.0, 0.0, [[1, 2], [3, 4]]], [0, 0, 90]), 
  ([1, 1.0, 1.5, 500, 0.0, 0.5, [[2, 3], [4, 5]]], [2, 3, 5])], 
 [([1, 1.5, 1.5, 500, 0.0, 0.0, [[300, 499],[577, 699]]], [4, 7, 8]), 
  ([1, 1.5, 1.5, 500, 0.0, 0.5, [[477, 599],[644, 788]]], [8, 4, 6])]]
```

How can I edit my code to achieve this? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `iter` + `zip`

```
it=iter(data1)
[list(zip(*l)) for l in zip(zip(it,it), data2)]
```

Output:

```
[[([1, 1.0, 1.5, 500, 0.0, 0.0, [[1, 2], [3, 4]]], [0, 0, 90]),
  ([1, 1.0, 1.5, 500, 0.0, 0.5, [[2, 3], [4, 5]]], [2, 3, 5])],
 [([1, 1.5, 1.5, 500, 0.0, 0.0, [[300, 499], [577, 699]]], [4, 7, 8]),
  ([1, 1.5, 1.5, 500, 0.0, 0.5, [[477, 599], [644, 788]]], [8, 4, 6])]]
```